# Scrollbars not appearing in SVG element

Tags: html, css, d3.js

I have an SVG being dynamically added to a div on my page using the following code:

```
var svg = d3.select("#svgholder").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.right + margin.left)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")")
    .style("overflow", "scroll");
```

In case anyone cares, here's where I define the relevant variables:

```
var margin = {top: 20, right: 180, bottom: 20, left: 180},
              width = 960 - margin.right - margin.left,
              height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;
```

and the placeholder div:

```
 <div style="background-color:white;" id="svgholder">
```

I can add scrollbars to the div just fine, but that only allows me to travel around the SVG, which is statically sized. When I place the object in the SVG, it's too big and just remains cut off at the farthest edges.

I tried adding scrollbars to the svg itself using the `.style("overflow", "scroll");` bit, but it has had no effect.

Am I missing something weird here?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the zoom to translate the content of the SVG

```
var svg = d3.select("svg"),
    g = svg.append("g");

// add stuff to g

var zoom = d3.zoom()
   .scaleExtent([1, 1])
   .translateExtent([[0, 0], [sizeXObject, sizeYObject]])
   .on("zoom", zoomed);

svg.call(zoom);

function zoomed() {
    g.attr("transform", d3.event.transform);
}
```

If you need to have margins you need to add a clip path `rect` to `g`.

Comment: I tried running this after my update function is called (which basically just computes a new graphic), but it also seems to have had no effect. If it helps, here's the code I'm using: http://bl.ocks.org/PandaRider/84b9c096e37334c2a4fd945a66b8ccf9 - I put your code snippet after the line that reads `d3.select(self.frameElement).style("height","500px");`